# Load Ajax content on same php page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm currently having trouble trying to send data to a same php page.
My problem is as follow: I'm submitting a form by Ajax, from a jQueryUI tab, and I'm trying to  send the data back to the same php page that was loaded in the tab.

Here is my code for the Ajax part, which is working as I can see the data coming back in the success part :

```
$('#query').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);            

    var request = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'tab_rechercher.php',
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(msg){
            alert(msg);
        }
    });             
});
```

Now that gives me an array, with the form data, plus the entire html page, which follows:

```
<form id="query" method="post" action="tab_rechercher.php">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Recherche d&apos;items dans une soumission ou bon de commande</legend>
    <table class="table_spacing">
        <tr>
            <td>Description de l&apos;item: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="item_description"></td>                
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="text-align:right;"><input id="rechercher" type="submit" value="Rechercher"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
```

The problem is that in my php page, the $_POST stays empty

```
if(empty($_POST) === false){
print_r($_POST);}
```

and the print never happens.

How can I get the data to be transferred back into the php page?
Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is.  You make an AJAX request and get back the data you expect?  What's failing?  Where is this check for `if(empty($_POST) === false)`?  When are you using it?  What request are you making when you perform this check?

Comment: The failing is that I get the data from the javascript by having that alert, but I don't get it inside the php. The check is in the php code, and I use it when I load the php page. It is only for testing purposes, and I just want to know if the data from the form gets sent to the php file

Comment: It sounds like you're misunderstanding the fundamental difference between client-side code and server-side code, and the ordering of requests and responses.  When your AJAX request goes to the PHP page, it's a POST request and the server-side code would be able to respond to that.  When you originally load the page, it's a GET request, so your conditional would behave differently at that time.  The data returned by the AJAX call is available client-side after that call, not to server-side code which executed *before* that call.  It's not clear at all what your order of events is here.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that out. Now, how can I respond to that resquet, so that the action is done on the server-side instead of the client-side?

Comment: Well, the AJAX request is handled server-side.  So you can perform any server-side actions you want when that request is made.  If after that AJAX request you then present the user with a new form or new options of some kind to collect more information client-side, then you'll need to make another request to server-side code (either AJAX or a standard form POST) to perform another server-side action.

Comment: How can I catch that request with the same php page and get the data that I need inside it? Do I need to use a loop? From what I can see, with the condition  (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])
 && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') it doesn't update itself and just catches the first one, which is the one done by setting the tab...

Comment: You are continuing to not understand client-side vs. server-side.  When you first load a page, the server-side code runs with the information it has (almost none at this point) and renders the page.  Subsequent requests (AJAX calls, form posts, navigating to another page, etc.) can add more information and allow more server-side code to run in response to those requests, rendering new responses.  If you have data on the client-side and want to send it to the server-side code, you make some sort of request (AJAX, for example) to a page and include that information in the request.

Comment: Is there a way to get that Ajax request inside the SAME php page? or because it has already loaded, there is no way? Can I make the code run again on the server-side so the information it has was updated? Maybe we could chat so this doesn't get overloaded?

Comment: Well, when the AJAX request receives its response, that client-side code can then alter the page however you need based on that response.  "Inside the same PHP page" is a very vague statement.  If your AJAX request is to the same URL which loaded the page, that's fine.  But it's not going to *automatically* make changes to the *instance* of the page that's *already been sent* to the client.  But your client-side code which is actively running in that instance certainly can.  So, for example, if the AJAX response contains a list of values then you can display those values with JavaScript.

Comment: 1) The request is to the same url which loaded the page. 2) I'm using a templating system server-side (Template-ITX), so I can't add a block from my html code to show? 3) Server-side, you can catch the request, but can only change the page with javascript? Am I right on those points?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you never actually post the form. You do post it via AJAX but it is in another 'thread', not the one you are currently viewing. To post it like you want, you need another function which will call just $('#query').submit();